# Suspicious delay after password entry in xfce

Tags: login

in short: it started since update from 19 (probably LTS) over 21.04 to 21.10 .

With wifi router on, it takes over two minutes from password entry till desktop to appear.
But if router is off, desktop appears immediately after login. And once the machine is "logged in", and I put it to sleep, desktop also appears immediately after "wake-up" password input.

It goes the same for all users. Turning "network manager" plugin off at startup, doesn't help. I checked syslog - nothing is happening: [image]

My computer is iMac model from arround 2010 with Nvidia graphics. I installed clamAV after upgrade, but scanning my home folder, /bin, /sbin and /lib folders reviled no threats.

I am in the dark. Which way should I go to at least diagnose, what is going on?

Regards,
Marjan

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: *"started since update from 19 to 21"* - this is ambiguous since you could possibly be referring to 19.04, 19.10, 21.04, or 21.10. They are all different releases. In any case this statement is problematic. All four of these releases are standard releases which only come with 9 months of support. All except 21.10 is EOL.  Both releases in 2019 have been EOL for a very long time and any supported upgrade path was long gone before any release in 2021 was ever available. This suggests that you have a very problematic installation which should probably be remedied with a new (clean) install.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 19, nor Ubuntu 21; Ubuntu's main releases are *year.month* in format (eg. Ubuntu 21.10 being the last 2021-October release), and *specialist* releases being *year* only; eg. Ubuntu Core 20; but Xfce is a desktop and isn't packaged for *specialist* releases so cannot be installed on Ubuntu Core 20 (also no specialist releases exist for *odd* years).

Comment: Ubuntu 19? I dont't recall that; it was probably LTS. Right now, Ubuntu version is 21.10.
I have done LTS upgrades in the past - it all went well.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 & 19.10 were **not** LTS releases; 19.04 upgraded to 19.10, which upgraded to 20.04 LTS. The LTS release is the first release of an *even* year (ie. 20.04 was the last LTS release; Ubuntu Core 20 though is a very different system as all *year* releases are *snap* only products; ie. there is no `apt` command in 20).  I'd stick to *supported* & QA-tested (*Quality Assurance*) upgrade paths for best results.

Comment: Any advice for diagnosing the delay then? It must be networking-related, but I have no idea how to determine the cause. What/where do I check, examine, test?

Comment: Can you try with a newly created user?

Comment: No difference with new user. Still two minutes pause from password entry till desktop to appear.
I have noticed the following: if at booting time, router is switched off and desktop appears immediately after entering  password, and I then log out, switch router on and login back - it again takes two minutes for desktop to appear.

Comment: If wifi is disabled at booting time, there is also no delay after password entry.

Answer (score 0):

Removal of all (connected and found) wifi networks in "nyetwork manager" panel, and re-registering my own wifi back, apparently solved the problem.